# Squashed Entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

The squashed entanglement of the system $\rho_{AB}$ is defined as:

\begin{equation}
E_{sq} (\rho_{AB}) = \inf \bigg[\dfrac{1}{2} I(A; B|E)_{\rho} : \rho_{ABE} \ \ \ \textrm{is an extension of } \ \ \rho_{AB} \bigg]
\end{equation}
Where $I(A;B|E)_{\rho}$ is the quantum conditional mutual information of $\rho_{ABE}$

\begin{equation}
I(A;B|E)_{\rho} := S(\rho_{AE}) +  S(\rho_{BE}) - S(\rho_{ABE})- S(\rho_{E}) 
\end{equation}

You can read more about it [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squashed_entanglement) .

**My question is**: If given a quantum state, how do you compute $I(A;B|E)_{\rho}$, so that you can find the infimum, and obtain the squashed entanglement? For example: 
Given the system $\rho_{AB} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 &  0 & 0 & 1 \\
   0 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 &  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $

which is fully entangled, how can I compute it using the squashed entanglement?
 For the entanglement of formation, it's fairly easy to compute since there is an explicit formula depends on $\rho$ but for the Squashed Entanglement, I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure states like the example you give, the squashed entanglement is just the normal entropy of entanglement (i.e., $S(\rho_A)$).  This follows trivially from the fact that all purifications of a pure state are of product form, $\rho_{ABE}=\rho_{AB}\otimes \rho_E$.

For mixed states, there exists no general way to compute squashed entanglement.

(By the way, I am not sure what you mean that it is "fairly easy" to compute entanglement of formation -- it is a pretty hard optimization problem. But of course, it is at least finite dimensional, which is not known to be the case for squashed entanglement.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I said that entanglement of formation is "fairly easy" to compute because I was thinking about the case of  two qubit system, since there's an explicit formula for that  (By Bennett and Wootters). I realized that I shouldn't have said that since for a bigger system, there's no explicit formula.  Again, thank you for your reply!